# String manipulation in Java

Tags: java, string

I wish to return a String as follows:

```
    Josephine Blow (Associate Professor, Math)
         Teaching Assignments: **(for each course write on a seperate line)**
          Course No.: xxx \t Section No.: xxxx \t Course Name: xxxx \t Day and Time: dayOfWeek - timeOfweek
          If no teaching assignments print: none
```

Using an ArrayList variable named "teaches", which from it I'm getting all my information.

I just can't understand how should I return this kind of a String, which can be very long.
Should I use some kind of String buffer? How can I add the seperate line between each two sections.

Here's my code, for make it clear:

```
public String toString() {
            String s ="";
            int i=1;
            if (this.teaches.isEmpty()){
                return "none";
            }

            for(Section current: this.teaches){
            s=s+"Course No"+i+" Section No:"+current.getSectionNo()+" Course Name:"+current.getRepresentedCourse().getCourseName()+" Day and Time"+current.getTimeOfDay();
            }

            return new String (this.getName()+" (Associatr Professor, "+this.department+" )"+s);

}
```

Comment: When this gets compiled, it will be converted to a StringBuilder (or StringBuffer, I forget) anyway, so in the end it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *strictly* need to use a `StringBuffer` or a `StringBuilder`. When Java concatenates two `String`s, it internally uses something that is very similar to a `StringBuffer`. Using `StringBuffer` directly is slightly better, though I think you won't notice it.

As of the newline, use the `\n` character. You can pipe many `\n` characters you like, that will insert some empty lines in the string.

For example:

```
s+="Course No"+i+" Section No:"+current.getSectionNo()+" CourseName:"+current.getRepresentedCourse().getCourseName()+" Day and Time"+current.getTimeOfDay()+"\n\n";
```

will leave an empty line between every course.

There are some special characters you can add using some codes that start with `\`. See: http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/character-escape-codes-in-java.html

Comment: How do I use it in my implementation?

Comment: Put literally `\n` at the end of every line, and put `\n\n` if you want to leave an empty line, too

Comment: this is not works good: s=s+"Course No"+i+" Section No:"+current.getSectionNo()+" Course Name:"+current.getRepresentedCourse().getCourseName()+" Day and Time"+current.getTimeOfDay()\n;
What did you mean?

Comment: `\n` has to be INSIDE the string, like any other character. s += "some line\n"

Comment: Or use System.getProperty("line.separator") - it's platform independent.

Comment: @duffymo: good point but that can be good or bad, depending on different cases. Sometimes I want `\n` to be used for consistency across platforms (i.e. in network applications), not the system line separator. More, `\n` works fine also on Windows terminal, so it's a problem only when you write to text files that you open with some dumb text editor like Notepad.

Comment: I can't do that. what do you mean INSIDE? can you please copy it with the additional?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, please use `StringBuilder`:

```
public String toString() 
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    if (!this.teaches.isEmpty())
    {
        for(Section current: this.teaches)
        {
            builder.append("["
                   .append("Course No ")
                   .append(i)
                   .append(" Section No: ")
                   .append(current.getSectionNo())
                   .append(" Course Name: ")
                   .append(current.getRepresentedCourse().getCourseName())
                   .append(" Day and Time ")
                   .append(current.getTimeOfDay())
                   .append("]");
        }
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Or, better yet, have a `Course` class instead of a bunch of raw Strings and just print out the `List<Course>`, calling its `toString()` method for each entry in the List.

Comment: or StringBuilder if access to it is via a single thread.  And add a new line via the \n character e.g. "Hello \n World".

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to StringBuffer you can use StringBuilder, recommended when you don't need synchronized access.

As for the newline, I'd recommend asking the System what is the appropriate end of line character(s), like this:

System.getProperty("line.separator");

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can construct your response with a StringBuffer or a StringBuilder (StringBuffer is thread safe but generally will be slightly less performant, so if you dont care about multi-threading use a StringBuilder)

for example:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(Section current: this.teaches){
            builder.append("Course No").append(i).append(" Section No:").append(current.getSectionNo()).append(" Course Name:").append(current.getRepresentedCourse().getCourseName()).append(" Day and Time").append(current.getTimeOfDay());
            }
```

You can include newlines using "\n" although you need to be careful using newlines as they can be system dependent, so prob better using

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

Comment: +1 Uhm, I find interesting the line.separator part, good point.